# Angular - Break line text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't save break line text into my database, how to solve this issue?

My save data suppose to be like this

```
I want to ask something.

Can I?
```

Not like this

```
I want to ask something. Can I?
```

html

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="" class="form-control" ng-model="rule.message" required></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="create()">Save</button>
```

js

```
myControllers.controller('MemberRuleCreateCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.rule = {};
        $scope.create = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://xxxxx.my/api/create_rule.php?&message=' + $scope.rule.message
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Rule successful created");
                $location.path('/member/rule');
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("No internet connection.");
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: That message should contain `\n\n` characters if there are line breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `encodeURIComponent()` function to encode the newlines correctly into the URL so it will be seen by the server correctly when you submit the GET request.

So your JS becomes:

```
myControllers.controller('MemberRuleCreateCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.rule = {};
        $scope.create = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://xxxxx.my/api/create_rule.php?&message=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.rule.message)
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Rule successful created");
                $location.path('/member/rule');
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("No internet connection.");
            });
        }
    }
]);
```